# Page Not Redirecting

Tags: java, scala, playframework

Everything seems fine, but the page won't redirect to the designated URL.

**`My Route`**

```
GET         /reset/ask                controllers.ResetController.ask()
```

**`My Controller`**

```
    public Result ask() {
    Form<AskForm> askForm = form(AskForm.class);
    return ok(views.html.reset.ask.render(askForm));
}
```

**`My View`**

View -> Reset -> ask.scala.html

**`My HTML`**

```
  <a href="@controllers.routes.ResetController.ask">Forgot Password?</a>
```

When I click the page, it just stays on the current page?

Any Suggestions? thanks

Comment: So you mean the page which html you show above (under **`My HTML`**) is not `ask.scala.html`, correct? If that's the case, you should include the generated html here, and clues about what your browser is doing, is it firing the expected request when you click the link? What is the response, ...

Comment: its validation issue, the page login overrides everything , after login i can access to ask page , how can I override the page ask before it runs login?

Comment: Seeing nothing about login in what you posted, there's no way I can help more than saying: bypass that validation issue/whatever for accessing the ask page.

Comment: I figure out the issue, I put secure authentication before the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed on gitter : The ResetController.ask() is protected by the @Secured annotation, while it should be exempt from that.